# Prove that $Z_{14}/(7)$ ≅ $Z_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Prove that $Z_{14}/(7)$ ≅ $Z_7$.

I understand that I have to show that there exists a surjective function relating the two and use the morphism theorem, but I'm not sure how in this case. Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know lagrange’s theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: There is one specific, very natural, surjective homomorphism $\Bbb Z_{14}\to\Bbb Z_7$ (it exists because $7$ divides $14$). Its kernel is $(7)$. And the image of any homomorphism is isomorphic to the domain divided by the kernel.

Comment: Is the homomorphism just x/2? @Arthur

Comment: @JamesDone Try that. Does it work? What is the result for, say, $x=3$? What I had in mind was even simpler. Consider this: If you know that $n\equiv 12\pmod{14}$ for some integer $n$, what is $n$ modulo $7$?

Comment: For some n, it would be 19 (mod 7).

Comment: @JamesDone Not just some, but _all_ such $n$. And if I forced you to pick a number from $0$ to $6$ instead of $19$, what would the result be? This is your homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_{14}$ to $\Bbb Z_7$.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I do not follow. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @JamesDone Look at a couple of integers that are congruent to $12$ modulo $14$. By that I mean write at least for our five such numbers down on a piece of paper. Then consider, for each one of them, whether it is congruent to $0,1,2,3,4,5$ or $6$ modulo $7$. Then try a couple of numbers that are congruent to $10$ modulo $14$, and do the same. What about numbers that are congruent to $2$ modulo $14$?

Comment: They seem to all be 5 mod 7.

Comment: @JamesDone Which is to say that the homomorphism I'm after maps $12\mapsto 5$. Note that $12\equiv5\pmod7$. This is going to be a pattern throughout. Now, what about the second case I gave you? With numbers congruent to $10$ modulo $14$.

Comment: Are you just trying to tell me that the function is simply finding the remainder of some n in $Z_{14}$ when divided by 7?

Comment: @JamesDone Yup. That's the one. Check that it is surjective, and see what the kernel is, and you're done.